# How Do I Implement a Popover in a Rails Partial Using Bootstrap 3?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-2

I currently have a Rails 4 application running Bootstrap 2 (gem twitter-bootstrap-rails 2.2.8). I was successful in implementing a popover using partials where a map is displayed when a link is clicked. Here is the code that I have.

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

bootstrap.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $(".popover-map").popover({ html : true })
```

_map

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span4" align="center" id="text-bold"><%= link_to("#{t :map_marfa_head}" , '#', class: "popover-map", rel: "popover", title: "#{t :map_marfa_head}", :"data-placement" => "bottom", :"data-content" => "#{render 'pages/map_marfa'}") %></div>
  <div class="span4" align="center" id="text-85"><%= "#{t :map_msg_click}" %></div>
  <div class="span4" align="center" id="text-bold"><%= link_to("#{t :map_bigbend_head}" , '#', class: "popover-map", rel: "popover", title: "#{t :map_bigbend_head}", :"data-placement" => "bottom", :"data-content" => "#{render 'pages/map_bigbend'}") %></div>
</div>
```

_map_marfa

```
<p align="center"><%= image_tag("map-marfa.jpg", alt: "#{t :map_marfa_head}") %></p>
```

_map_bigbend

```
<p align="center"><%= image_tag("map-bigbend.jpg", alt: "#{t :map_bigbend_head}") %></p>
```

When I click either link the map display below and stays there until the person clicks the link again to close the map. I have copied the code to my new Rails 5 Bootstrap 3 application. Here are the code changes for Bootstrap 3.

application.js

```
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

bootstrap.js.coffee was renamed to bootstrap.coffee

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

_map

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4" align="center" id="text-bold"><%= link_to("#{t :map_marfa_head}" , '#', class: "popover-map", rel: "popover", title: "#{t :map_marfa_head}", :"data-placement" => "bottom", :"data-content" => "#{render 'pages/map_marfa'}") %></div>
  <div class="col-md-4" align="center" id="text-85"><%= "#{t :map_msg_click}" %></div>
  <div class="col-md-4" align="center" id="text-bold"><%= link_to("#{t :map_bigbend_head}" , '#', class: "popover-map", rel: "popover", title: "#{t :map_bigbend_head}", :"data-placement" => "bottom", :"data-content" => "#{render 'pages/map_bigbend'}") %></div>
</div>
```

Now when I click either link the map displays and immediately disappears instead of staying until the link is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I kept looking at this and realized that in `application.js` I required turbolinks. For whatever reason it messes up things I try to do. I removed `//= require turbolinks` and my scripts work again. Go figure.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm having problems again with this. Running the same logic in Rails 5.0.2 and bootstrap-sass 3.1.7 my maps no longer work.